# What does the plot of the Fourier series of f look like?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Consider the Fourier series of f, defined using the interval −1 ≤ x ≤ 1.
Plot f together with its Fourier series (the plot should show several periods of the Fourier series).
(i) $$f(x) = 1$$
(ii) $$f(x) =x^2$$

What does a plot of these Fourier series look like?  Thank you so much for any help or hints!

Answer (score 0):

The Fourier series of a constant is $1$, and the Fourier transform of $t^2$ is $-2 e^{-i t}-2 e^{i t}+\frac{1}{2} e^{-2 i t}+\frac{1}{2} e^{2 i t}-\frac{2}{9} e^{-3 i
   t}-\frac{2}{9} e^{3 i t}+\frac{1}{8} e^{-4 i t}+\frac{1}{8} e^{4 i t}-\frac{2}{25}
   e^{-5 i t}-\frac{2}{25} e^{5 i t}+\frac{\pi ^2}{3}$.

Comment: The OP doesn't ask for Fourier Transform but for Fourier Series...

Comment: The OP asks the Fourier Series on $[-1,1]$ not $[-\pi, \pi]$... Besides, I don't think that a raw result like the one you give without converting it into a $cos(nt)$ version brings much understanding for the _plotting_ of this function which is the ultimate goal of the OP.